# Automated UI testing in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We're attempting to set up automated UI testing for our CRM 2013 development. We've attempted to use both CodedUI and Selenium but they both struggle to get references to elements on the forms. Especially the Site Map.

Has anyone had any luck with automated UI testing in CRM 2013? We'd prefer to use CodedUI.

Comment: Awfully quiet here. I'm taking that as not good news.

Comment: We're getting some success using a combination of CodedUI and Selenium web driver ExecuteJavaScript. When CodedUI fails and struggles, we target the Xrm.Page methods to carry out the equivalent of what we're attempting to do with the mouse. It ain't pretty but it sort of works.

Comment: Visual studio webtest is not an option ??

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently on a project where we use CodedUI with CRM 2011 and I must say that they seem to bite each other. Finding controls/ui-elements is very slow and unstable (having different results after repeating the same tests a couple of times, sometimes finding and sometimes not finding the same buttons, etc). When you dive into the html-source we also notice that CRM does not even guarantee that the id-attribute of elements is unique, and even when they are CodedUI is still not always able to find the element.

We are now fiddling with the SearchProperties and tweaking the PlaybackSettings to get reasonable stable results, but if tests work they run very, very slow. I do hope to see some magic solution for this problem but unfortunately I cannot provide any more advise than just to define the Search- and FilterProperties very tight by hand and increasing control lookup timeouts to ensure controls are found and accept very slow run-speeds.

Answer (score 1):

QTP works well with it. My colleague tested few scenarios

Answer (score 1):

We can automate CRM 2013 UI using CodedUI and any ui scenario can be automated which includes all the scenarios like Sitemap, Lookup, Datetime, Assign, Entity Navigation and related entities and also there is a way too to do Data Driven Testing as well as CSV or Excel or SQL database as source. If you could include CRM 2013 sdk to validate data and controls types that would be much better and easy. I could able to automate both CRM 2011 and CRM 2013 using single code base on condition CRM version 5 or 6. The only thing which I could not able to automate compared to CRM 2011 is CCA/CCD Vs USD.

Coming to your question for automating the sitemap. First mouse hover the main "Microsoft Dynamics CRM" TAB and then Click Service/Settings/Sales/... similarly the same way for other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Validate that you're getting the correct element ids by checking through Developer Tools.